align text in radial plot
I am trying to use this code (https://r-graph-gallery.com/297-circular-barplot-with-groups.html), but with long names longnameA, longnameB, longnameC, longnameD. Is there a way to properly align this text around the inner circle of the radial plot?
# library
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataset
data <- data.frame(
  individual=paste( "Mister ", seq(1,60), sep=""),
  group=factor(c( rep('longnameA', 10), rep('longnameB', 30), rep('longnameC', 14), rep('longnameD', 6))) ,
  value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar <- 3
to_add <- data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group), ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) <- colnames(data)
to_add$group <- rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar)
data <- rbind(data, to_add)
data <- data %>% dplyr::arrange(group)
data$id <- seq(1, nrow(data))

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data <- data
number_of_bar <- nrow(label_data)
angle <- 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust <- ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle <- ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data <- data %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))

# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data <- base_data
grid_data$end <- grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start <- grid_data$start - 1
grid_data <- grid_data[-1,]

# Make the plot
ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar
  
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  
  
  geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  ylim(-100,120) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() + 
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=value+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  
  # Add base line information
  geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +
  geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, angle = c(360), fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)

p



One option would be to use geomtextpath. See my recent answer using the code from the R graph gallery.

@stefan Thank you. Just adding solved the problem:
# Add base line information   geomtextpath::geom_textsegment(     data = base_data,     aes(       x = start, y = -.1,       xend = end, yend = -.1,       label = group     ),     colour = "black",     linewidth = 0.6,     size = 8 / .pt,     inherit.aes = FALSE,     gap = FALSE,     offset = unit(-20, "pt")   ) 
